# How can we achieve high chart with complex json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

If we have complex Json Data like as below:

```
[{
"type":"a",
"Key1":25,
"Key2":100,
"Key3":105,
"value": [{"Key100":50,
"Key200":0,
"Key300":10,}]
},
{
"type":"b",
"Key1":60,
"Key2":400,
"Key3":150,
"value": [{"Key100":30,
"Key200":30,
"Key300":0,}]
},
{
"type":"c",
"Key1":35,
"Key2":80,
"Key3":85,
"value": [{"Key100":55,
"Key200":50,
"Key300":60,}]
}]
```

I have done grouped based on "Type" for above data, and tried to achieve column graph using high chart.

But still not able to achieve graph based this data.

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific about what you want to do with the data, what code you're working with, and what part(s) of it is not working the way that you want.  Short answer: the way to make a chart with complex JSON is to parse the data that you need out of the JSON and into a format that Highcharts understands. For a more specific answer, need a more specific question. In the meantime, read the docs: http://www.highcharts.com/docs | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: I have already explained that i want to display column chart based on "type" field grouping from above JSON data. I understand that i need to format json that highcharts can understand... To format\parse json data i have tried     _.groupBy and _.keys function from underscore and lodash library.. but still not able to format that highcharts can be understand.

Comment: It is still not clear how you want to visualise the data except it should be a column chart. See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/s24wzj8c/ and refer to it. So type in fact are categories or series? What are "KeyX" and what are "value"?

Comment: please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5x1ent1n/5/,  i have visualize above json data in high chart using underscore.js functional java-script library.

Comment: Ok, so...what is the question then?

Comment: As you can see.. question is solved now. still i am working on Json where key is not same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can display complex JSON data with highchart by transform data which highchart can be understand.

To represent data into highchart, we will need to transform data into point configuration with in data array. please follow this 
[Highchart (THE DATA IN A SERIES)](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series) to understand highchart series concepts.